# Looking for Linked Files in Illustrator .ai file imported into CorelDraw

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw

I am trying to check for linked files in a .ai file that I am opening in CorelDraw.  From what I can tell is always strips them out. Is this always the case? I tried both import and open and neither seems to handle it properly.  I am running CorelDraw X8.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the CorelDraw format, .cdr, is **not** a *universal* format.

Adobe apps kind of *require* either a universal format (eps, pdf, tiff) or an Adobe file format for links.

Adobe doesn't bother trying to support *proprietary* formats for file links other than their own proprietary formats.